# Rails rename_column, but keep old versions in tact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I initially released my first Rails app (an API for our iPhone application) a few weeks ago, but last night I noticed I had misspelled a column name. I am going to rename the column, but when I do this it will break the iPhone application because it will be spelled differently.

What is the best way to keep the old iPhone application intact post-rename of my column? I am deploying the rails app on Heroku, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the column, then create an alias of it with the old, incorrect name. E.g.:

```
alias_attrib :wrong_name, :right_name
```

Then wait for the day when the old iPhone app no longer needs to be supported, and remove the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the new one and an alias of the old until you have all, or almost all your clients updated to the latest version which will access only the right column.

After your clients stop using (or its usage nears zero) the the alias, drop it.